# How to load a UINavigationController from a XIB or storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, xib

I have a custom UINavigationController class and I've been looking for a way to load the Navigation Bar from a XIB, or Story Board.  I made a XIB and set the class of a Navigation Controller in a Storyboard to the custom class.  I've come up with this so far in viewDidLoad:

```
var navView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ActionBarNavController", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    self.navigationItem
```

That will load the xib, but it covers the entire screen.  It does the same thing in UINavigationControllerDelegate willShowViewController.  I know how to setup the Nav Bar in code, I'm just looking for a way to get it setup from a XIB.